# Average attack bonus of a 30th level character in DnD 4e

Tags: dnd-4e, attack-roll, epic-tier, statistics

What is the average attack of 30th level D&D character? (Of course this number must be calculated without uber-strong homebrew items).

My real question is this: What is the average chance of average character to hit some late game boss like Demogorgon (AC:48, Reflex:43)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what a Level 30 character could have, if optimized to hit.

- +15 Levels
- +10 prime stat of 30 (assumes an extra +2 to the prime stat from Epic Destiny)
- +3  an expertise feat
- +6  a +6 weapon
- +3  weapon proficiency bonus

That's +37 without anything special added.  You'll need an 11+ to hit Demogorgon, right at 50/50.  Attacks against other defenses vary considerably, but figure 2 less as a rule of thumb.

A character not as optimized to hit will be probably 2 less:

- Not having a stat boost due to an Epic Destiny
- Using a weapon with only a +2 proficiency bonus

There are several ways for a character to improve his or her chance to hit

- Fighter weapon talent
- Rogues weapon talent
- Kensei Focus
- accurate implements

A character devoted to hitting should get an extra +1 from somewhere.  Throw in `Combat Advantage` and you are swinging at +40.  That should be enough to have a reasonable chance to hit most anything.